# Find and move specific words in filenames

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have the following problem, there are files with the following names: `1234_43v5_2ws4.bsw.3r5_3d5_9z5` here is only the `.bsw.` is important everything else is subject to change.

There is a main folder, e.g. `C:/Data/Main`; in the `Main` folder there are different folders that have different names and in there also are different folders that have different names but they have the `xxx_xxx.bsw.xxx_xxx` files that I need.

How can i find the different `.bsw.` files and move this to the target folder.

Ive tryed this one

```
source_dir= pathlib.Path('C:/Data/Main/')
target_dir= pathlib.Path('C:/Data/bswdata')

for p in source_dir.glob('*.bsw.*'):
    shutil.move(p, target_dir / p.name)
```

The Code is running without Issues but the files are not moved .. is there a problem with the some folders?

Comment: You can do this from a command line.  No programming is required.  `move \data\Main\*.bsw.* \data\bswdata`.

Comment: The text says that the files are in subdirectories. You're not recursing into the subdirectories, you're only processing files that are directly in the `Main` directory.

Comment: Is there only one level deep of subfolders? Do you want to keep the subfolder strucutre in the target? If you have excactly one level of subfolders and don't want to keep the structure, then `for p in source_dir.glob('*/*.bsw.*'):`.

Comment: @tdelaney the maximum is 3 level deep of subfolders. 
No I only need the .bzw. Files not the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your glob pattern isn't searching the subdirectories that contain the files. From [`pathlib.Path.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob)

> Patterns are the same as for fnmatch, with the addition of “**” which
> means “this directory and all subdirectories, recursively”. In other
> words, it enables recursive globbing

```
for p in source_dir.glob('**/*.bsw.*'):
    shutil.move(p, target_dir / p.name)
```

Comment: now i have a problem, with one file works fine but if i have two files i get an error: return os.path.basename(path.rstrip(sep))
AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'rstrip' that is because he creats an folder from folder 1 bsw data but for folder2 with the bsw datas he can`t move them

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try to find where the error is coming and whats its cause by using any suitable exception handeling method like:

Method 1: You can check using print statement if program is itirating through file and attempting them to move like:

```
for p in source_dir.glob('*.bsw.*'):
    print(f"Moving {p} to {target_dir / p.name}")
    shutil.move(p, target_dir / p.name)
```

Method 2: or you can better use try and except to know why the files are not being moved and correct your code accordingly like :

```
import shutil
import pathlib

source_dir = pathlib.Path('C:/Data/Main/')

target_dir = pathlib.Path('C:/Data/bswdata')

try:

    for p in source_dir.glob('*.bsw.*'):

        print(f"Moving {p} to {target_dir / p.name}")

        shutil.move(p, target_dir / p.name)

except Exception as e:

    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

Comment: On both Methods, it doesn`t work and i also didn`t get an Error.